# Lombok @Data and @Builder combination

Tags: java, lombok

Hi I have a question about @Data and @Builder combination.
Let's imagine the situation: I have Entity which has to be created and modified.
Firstly I create it:

```
Entity entity = Pojo.builder()
.a("1")
.b("2")
.build();
```

After some operations, I have to add `c` field and modify `a`.
How I have to do that?
Is this normal to do:

```
entity.setA("01");
entity.setC("3");
repo.save(entity);
```

Is there any better variants?

Comment: You can use @Accessors keyword on Entity.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That's fine. 
Buider -> object creation, Set -> object setting after creation.

The intent of the Builder design pattern is to separate the construction of a complex object from its representation. It is one of the Gang of Four design patterns.

Comment: Makes me wonder, if you are ok with mutability then what is the builder really giving you.

Comment: @Michael I believe the same, builder are meant to provide a immutable object and its used so that we don't mutate the object once formed.

Comment: Personally I think that immutability and fluent interfaces are separate concerns. It may be that you find immutability in general to b a best practice. But this would be whether or not you used a fluent builder. E.g Fluent builders avoid writing telescopic constructors ( multiple optional fields).

Comment: @Michael builder has nothing to do with mutability or immutability, so the builder is giving you everything that the builder pattern is supposed to give you

Comment: @Kronen It's been 3 years since that comment, so I can't read my own mind, but I think the gist was: what's the point to instantiate a builder that you set fields on, only to produce a mutable instance, when you can just instantiate the mutable instance and call setters on it. In that case, a builder is pointless indirection.

Comment: @Michael but that is not the point of the question, he specifically says 'Let's imagine the situation: I have Entity which has to be created and modified.' And my point is that builder pattern is all about creation of objects. It doesn't address mutability.. Whether to mutate them or not is your decision.

Comment: @Kronen of course it's related to the question. Why call `Pojo.builder().a("01").build()` when you call `new Entity().setA("01")` (provided your setter returns 'this')? If the class being built is mutable the the boilerplate of your builder is achieving nothing, except extra garbage for the GC

Comment: @Michael Imagine a complex object that requires laborious, step-by-step initialization of many fields and nested objects. Such initialization code is usually buried inside a monstrous constructor with lots of parameter. That's the point of a builder, it is NOT an immutable record, you want to mutate that object and you want to mutate it a lot. So you are achieving everything with it, you are achieving what the builder pattern is all about. When you confuse a builder with a record or a Value annotated class then that is your own mistake.

Comment: @Michael and even worst you don't even understand what he was trying to do, he is not creating a new object with `new Entity().setA("01")` which would be pointless, he is calling `myEntity.setA("01")` the setter of the created object to mutate it.

Comment: @Kronen if you think I confused a builder for a record then you have not understood anything I've written.

Comment: @Michael no, you don't understand, the point of the builder pattern is and I cite from the GoF book "to separate the construction of a complex object from its representation so that the same construction process can create different representations."  It's not the point to pass the builder around your whole application to finish its building in a deep layer based on some business logic.

Comment: @Kronen I understand perfectly well that you have no grasp on what I was saying. Feel free to reply again but I won't be reading it.

Comment: @Michael I know perfectly what you were saying, you can keep talking all you want about something you don't understand. When you say `if the class being built is mutable then the boilerplate of your builder is achieving nothing' you are wrong.  It achieved the creation of the object PERIOD It doesn't matter how many times you mutate that object later without using what you call the boilerplate generated code. It just nonsense and it's not going to become true no matter how many times you keep repeating this nonsense. You should know better.

Answer (score 2):

You can use setter always using `@Accessors(chain = true)` on entity to create object and to set field. The chain option gives us setters that return this.

```
Entity entity= new Entity().setName("Name").setBalance(10);
entity.setName("newName");
```

Note that `chain` defaults to true, but I set it explicitly for clarity.

And for accessors without get or set prefix use `@Accessors(fluent = true)`

```
Entity entity= new Entity().name("Name").balance(10);
```

Comment: Using "javabean pattern" to create objects is probably the worst solution compared to classic constructors and fluent builder pattern. Between the moment when you create the object `new Entity()` and time calling setters your object "could" be in an inconsistent state. Better to think as "object created" = "consistent/finished object".

Comment: @CodeScale `time calling setters your object "could" be in an inconsistent state` thats not right actually. As OP need both options then its better to use same pattern I think.

Comment: @CodeScale Can you explain why you think it's the worst solution? And why builder pattern is suitable for this case(mutable object) ?

Comment: He don't need setters for B in his example.  By the way javabean way is the only creational  pattern that create the object and then populate it... As I said it is better to have coherent object at creation time (mutable or not). This is explained in effective java book from Josh bloch